# How to assign values received from the ipcRenderer to a separate variable in another script?

Tags: node.js, electron, ipc

New to electron, tried sending some values from the index.js to the index.html using ipcRenderer, the original tutorial had the values being logged to the dev console but I want these values to be stored in a variable. Can someone help me with this?

In index.js :

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const os_nat = require('os');
let cpu = os_nat.cpus();
let cpu_mod = cpu[0].model;
mainWindow.webContents.send('cpu_model', cpu_mod);
```

In the mainwindow declaration :

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
width: 800,
height: 600,
webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true}
```

And then in the index.html :

```
<script>
    const electron = require('electron');
    const ipcRenderer = electron.ipcRenderer;
    ipcRenderer.on('cpu_model', (event, data) => {
        let cpu_mod = data; 
    });

    console.log(cpu_mod);
```

The problem is that the `cpu_mod` variable throws an undefined variable error

So how can I assign the `data` value received to a variable, so that it can be used later in the script?

Comment: Move `console.log(...)` inside your `ipcRenderer.on(...)` callback like 
`
ipcRenderer.on('cpu_model', (event, data) => {
        let cpu_mod = data; 
        console.log(cpu_mod);
    });
`

Comment: But I want to use the `cpu_mod` variable outside the callback, is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Fast and dirty - define the variable with `var` on one level up from current definition